# nicer paths to partial views of subclasses when rendering a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, collections, path, partial

Suppose I have:

```
class Edible
end
class Apple < Edible
end
class Orange < Edible
end
```

I am rendering a collection of these edibles, regardless of their actual type:

```
<%= render @edibles %>
```

This works, but Rails wants me to place these views in `apples/apple` and `oranges/orange`.

Is there a way to tell Rails to look for views in the same folder, i.e. `edibles/apple` and `edibles/orange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def partial
    edible_type.class.name.underscore ##edible type can be apple or orange
  end

<% @edibles.each do |edible| %>
  <%= render( :partial => "edibles/#{edible.partial}", :locals => {:edible => edible}) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I was hoping there's some obscure way of doing it without resorting to `each`. Guess not. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can render collection without using **each**:

```
<%= render partial: "edibles/edible", collection: @edibles, as: :edible %>
```